# Data from multiple tables returns to many records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get data from different tables. 
below are the table structure and values and what i tried so far.

```
uploadtable
uploadId    doctypeId
1             1
2             1

MetadataTable
Id   doctypeId   contentLable   controlType   fieldtype  
1       1        docnumber       Textbox       varchar
2       1        expiryDate      Textbox       Datetime

contentTable
Id   uploadId  doctypeId    Label        Value
1       1        1          docnumber    123
2       1        1          expiryDate   1/1/2016
```

When I pass `uploadId` as 1 in where condition then Output should be

```
uploadId  contentLable  controlType  fieldtype  Label        Value
1         docnumber      Textbox     varchar    docnumber    123
1         expiryDate     Textbox     Datetime   expiryDate   1/1/2016
```

Actually O tried in my sql server as below. Actually I need linq query. If I get correct output in sql then I thought of converting it ti linq.

```
select
    upd.uploadId,
    meta.contentLable,
    meta.controlType,
    meta.fieldtype,
    content.Label,
    content.value
from MetadataTable meta,
    contentTable content,
    uploadtable upd
where upd.uploadId = content.uploadId 
and meta.doctypeId = content.doctypeId 
and upd.uploadId = 1
```

I am getting incorrect output as below.

```
uploadId  contentLable  controlType  fieldtype  Label        Value
1         docnumber      Textbox     varchar    docnumber    123
1         docnumber      Textbox     varchar    expiryDate   1/1/2016
1         expiryDate     Textbox     Datetime   docnumber    123
1         expiryDate     Textbox     Datetime   expiryDate   1/1/2016
```

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: I have put sql query above. I tried to write sql query. If i get correct output in sql then i can convert it to linq.

Comment: You need to use joins to connect he relationships between you tables

Comment: I have used joins but i am getting incorrect output. For example when i execute above query i will get 4 rows of data. In that only first and last rows are correct. Middle two row of data i am getting incorrect

Comment: I have updated my question with output of query what i am currently getting.

Comment: Can anyone suggest me where i am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NIRANJANG - is this related to linq ot asp.net? or is it still in the stage where your sql is incorrect?

Comment: yes i need sql query. still my sql is incorrect.

Comment: @NIRANJANG - I removed the linq and asp.net tags from the question because this is a sql question. Once you get this one to work and after trying yourself to convert it to linq, using the many references on line ([like this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/68/linq-queries/2994/joins-inner-left-right-cross-and-full-outer-joins#t=201608230735121229183)) then if you still fail to convert it then you can post a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps. I think this sql should perform what you need:

```
select upd.uploadId,
    meta.contentLable,
    meta.controlType,
    meta.fieldtype,
    content.Label,
    content.value
from uploadtable upd
join metadataTable meta
on upd.doctypeId = meta.doctypeId
join contentTable content
on upd.doctypeId = content.doctypeId
and upd.uploadId = content.uploadId    <---------- This is what you are missing
where upd.uploadId = 1
```

1. Avoid selecting from several tables using `from x,y,z` - use instead proper `join` syntax - it will make your queries more readable and will reduce chances of forgetting joining conditions.
2. When joining to `contentTable` you need to also join by both the `uploadId` and the `doctypeId` - otherwise you will get a `Cartesian join`/`cross join` like you did.

Comment: @NIRANJAN G - Does it help you understand the problem?

Comment: but i dont have uploadId in MetadataTable? I am trying. Thanks a lot

Comment: @NIRANJANG - Can you check now?

Comment: yes i am checking. on upd.uploadId = content.uploadId. I think this should be and. Am i right?

Comment: Hi Gilad, Still i am getting same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121595/discussion-between-niranjan-g-and-gilad-green).